# How to show external html / web pages inside android app?

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to create an android app which will show multiple web urls to users based on their choice. If a user clicks on a link I want the external website to open inside my app so that user can easily go back to other links after visiting the side. I am using web view and each time it is opening a browser , which I don't want. As sometimes it is difficult for user to go back to app. I want something like a web page opening inside a frame .

I am using the following code in my activity.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Thanks in advance for any help .
Shakti

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes then you need to create [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Check Step No. 7 and 8 given in [Hello WebView example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html)..

Comment: @user825707 As per SO rule, you should upvote/accept answer if it helps.