# How to make webview like in Gmail?

Tags: android, webview

I think everybody uses Gmail and knows that it can open links inside it. It has Webview (I think) and toolbar where we have homesUp back button, link preview and options menu. How to make it? Is it open api or only custom webview with layout? And how to make good webview for the app? What does it have to have except webview?

Comment: `WebView` is `WebView`! There is no any `WebView` in `GMail` like `Custom WebView`! They have web pages which are good looking design which are just attracting you!!

Comment: May be you are looking for Custom tabs https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs ?

Comment: Check [How to show external html / web pages inside android app?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835497/how-to-show-external-html-web-pages-inside-android-app)

Comment: @NickBapu I think the OP wants to copy the behaviour of GMAIL (The Native Android App, *not* the web app), which is indeed able to open a web page.

Comment: @Bracadabra, I saw it, but I have to add some buttons below web-content so I decided to use my own layout

Comment: @Benoit, I have made opening links inside app, but right now I need some customization for making its looking better